# Parsley.js Not Validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

```
<!-- Load jQuery from Google CDN !-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load jQuery Validation Code !-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parsley-standalone.min.js"></script>

        <form data-validate="parsley" data-show-errors="true" method="post" action="php/mail.php">

            <input type="text" class="contact_field" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" data-required="true">

            <input type="text" class="contact_field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" name="email" data-required="true">

            <textarea class="contact_field" placeholder="Question or Comment" rows="8" name="message" data-required="true"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" class="contact_button" value="Send!">

            <input type="reset" class="contact_button" value="Reset">

        </form>
```

Every time I try to submit form, no validation occurs. A blank form easily passes and send the e-mail. Any idea what I'm doing wrong with this script?

Comment: Use Firebug or Safari's web inspector to debug your JS code.  See what errors are being thrown and update your question with them.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out with that. *facepalm*

Comment: The answer did help me in this case as it allowed me to see a javascript error which forced me to realize I made a huge oversight in the parsley.js file I included. Thank you!

Comment: you should post what was the problem